# Implementing Whiteboard pattern the right way?

Tags: java, osgi

Consider the following code snippet from http://www.knopflerfish.org/osgi_service_tutorial.html#best explaining whiteboard pattern

```
ServiceListener sl = new ServiceListener() {
public void serviceChanged(ServiceEvent ev) {
  ServiceReference sr = ev.getServiceReference();
  switch(ev.getType()) {
  case ServiceEvent.REGISTERED:
    {
          registerServlet(sr);
    }
    break;
  case ServiceEvent.UNREGISTERING:
    {
          unregisterServlet(sr);
    }
    break;
  }
}
  };

String filter = "(objectclass=" + HttpServlet.class.getName() + ")";
try {
  bc.addServiceListener(sl, filter); // -- 1
  ServiceReference[] srl = bc.getServiceReferences(null, filter); // -- 2
  for(int i = 0; srl != null && i < srl.length; i++) {
sl.serviceChanged(new ServiceEvent(ServiceEvent.REGISTERED,
                   srl[i]));
  }
} catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Is there a possibility of duplicating the ServiceEvent.REGISTERED event between
line-1 and line-2 ? After registering the service listener in line-1 and just before line-2 ,  a service registers itself causing the listener to receive ServiceEvent.REGISTERED notification. In line-2 amongst all the service references is a reference to this service causing the notification to be received twice. Is this scenario possible ? If yes then what can be done to avoid this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [ServiceTracker](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html) instead of trying to do it using the "raw" API. ServiceTracker will handle these issues properly for you.

Even better is to use Declarative Services.

Comment: I agree. I guess what I would like to know is if this scenario even likely?

Comment: Yes. It is likely which is why Service Tracker and DS exist.